# I can't seem to get the keys working for a new jqGrid Row with Inline Editing

Tags: jqgrid

I am having an issue with getting the keys (Esc and Enter) to work on a new record.  Below is the code for my add button:

```
$("#t_clients").append('<button type="button" onclick="$(\'#clients\').jqGrid(\'addRow\', {addRowParams: {extraparam: {keys: true}} });">Add Client</button>');
```

According to the documentation, it seems like this should be working.  Unfortunately, it doesn't.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the parameter

```js
{addRowParams: {extraparam: {keys: true}} }
```

of [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#addrow) method to

```js
{addRowParams: {keys: true}}
```